# Smarty template, document expired issue

Tags: php, smarty

I use smarty template language in my php project. It works great except I'm getting:

> Document Expired, This document is no longer available.

error every time I click back button in browser. I did not change any settings in php or smarty.

Comment: im running smarty havent ran into this issue, but it sounds like a cache issue, i would read through this http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching.tpl

Comment: maybe the fact that i DON'T use cache, is it mandatory?

Comment: It doesn't sound like it's attached to Smarty, but rather something with the browser and it's caching. Is the page you're trying to get to the results of a POST? (BTW, cache is not mandatory. We run fine with it off.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with smarty. When previous page was generated via POST request (submitting a form) then back button gives this message. It is perfectly normal behaviour. A page generated by submitting a form should not be available via back button. To get rid of it use GET method (querystring in URL).